# How to make hyperref work with bibitem keys containing a colon and using babel french option?

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, citing, babel, active-characters

As seen in [this thread](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2014-September/035855.html), the `\cite` command bugs when the selected language is French and a bibitem key contains a `:`, which is an active character in babel french.
Indeed, concerned hyperlinks always refer to page 1 instead of the anchor to the bibliography item.

Apparently, this is a bug of `hyperref` and can be resolved in several ways, e.g.:

- enclosing each `\cite` by a `\selectlanguage{english}` ... `\selectlanguage{french}`
- using the `cite` package (cf [this reply](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2014-September/035864.html))
- etc.

Using the `cite` package seems the most simple and elegant workaround so far to me.
But what if I *cannot* use this package and still want an elegant solution, what do you think it would be?

Comment: The really elegant solution is to use biblatex.

Comment: Could you tell me more about this?

Answer (score 3):

This should really be solved by `hyperref`, but here's a hack that seems to work (for the colon); however, the best thing, when `babel-french` is involved, is not to use colons in labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% patch \hyper@link@ so \FDP@colonspace becomes innocuous
\patchcmd{\hyper@link@}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\def\FDP@colonspace{}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{a:b}

\newpage

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{a:b} X

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The link at page 1 will point to the bibliography item.